# My MediaPlayer stops playing about 20 seconds after phone goes to sleep

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

my `MediaPlayer` stops playing after phone goes to sleep about 20 to 30 seconds after . my failed attempt is below thanks in advance.

```
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    SeekBar seekBar;
    boolean wasPlaying = false;
    ImageButton fab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mediaplayer);

        fab = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                playSong();
            }
        });

        final TextView seekBarHint = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                seekBarHint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {
                seekBarHint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                int x = (int) Math.ceil(progress / 1000f);

                if (x < 10)
                    seekBarHint.setText("0:0" + x);
                else
                    seekBarHint.setText("0:" + x);

                double percent = progress / (double) seekBar.getMax();
                int offset = seekBar.getThumbOffset();
                int seekWidth = seekBar.getWidth();
                int val = (int) Math.round(percent * (seekWidth - 2 * offset));
                int labelWidth = seekBarHint.getWidth();
                seekBarHint.setX(offset + seekBar.getX() + val
                        - Math.round(percent * offset)
                        - Math.round(percent * labelWidth / 2));

                if (progress > 0 && mediaPlayer != null && !mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    clearMediaPlayer();
                    fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MediaPlayerActivity.this, android.R.drawable.ic_media_play));
                    MediaPlayerActivity.this.seekBar.setProgress(0);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


                if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void playSong() {

        try {


            if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                clearMediaPlayer();
                seekBar.setProgress(0);
                wasPlaying = true;
                fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MediaPlayerActivity.this, android.R.drawable.ic_media_play));
            }


            if (!wasPlaying) {

                if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                }

                fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MediaPlayerActivity.this, android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause));

                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String user_name = intent.getStringExtra("USER_NAME");
                String file = intent.getStringExtra("FILE_NAME");

                TextView Namee = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                Namee.setText(file);

                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(user_name);

                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f);
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
                seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());

                mediaPlayer.start();
                new Thread(this).start();

            }

            wasPlaying = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public void run() {

        int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        int total = mediaPlayer.getDuration();


        while (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && currentPosition < total) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }

            seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        clearMediaPlayer();
    }

    private void clearMediaPlayer() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because when your phone sleeps, your activity destroyed after a certain time base on your free ram and other

The point is, for a long running task like music play, an activity is not an option. Activity mostly is, only for tasks which needs user focus, interaction and not running for an infinite time in the background.

Music player and such long running job need to use service, which runs indefinitely until the user or OS destroys it.

From google [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) about service

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background, and it doesn't provide a user interface. Another application component can start a service, and it continues to run in the background even if the user switches to another application. Additionally, a component can bind to a service to interact with it and even perform interprocess communication (IPC). For example, a service can handle network transactions, play music, perform file I/O, or interact with a content provider, all from the background.

To say specifically, for a music app, you need Foreground Service

> A foreground service performs some operation that is noticeable to the user. For example, an audio app would use a foreground service to play an audio track. Foreground services must display a Notification. Foreground services continue running even when the user isn't interacting with the app.